# WebSphere Application Server Node Agent Shutting down automatically

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

Let me explain my environment setup

WAS version : 8.5 
OS : AIX

we have 1 DMGR, 6 Node agents and 6 nodes. Recently we faced one problem.  node agents are  shutting down automatically. Log says "Too many open file". We used LSOF commands to monitor the Node agent process ID.

Some kernal parameter. 
hardfile limit: 20000 
softfile limit: 8126

This is the monitoring output.

`Date Server 1 Node Agent PID(6054) Server 2 Node Agent PID(8076) 
29/11/2015 1636 1641 
30/11/2015 2382 2390 
01/12/2015 4527 4534 
02/12/2015 5265 5274`

Node agent process only keeps on opening the file. it is not closing the file descriptor. IBM Suggested to upgrade to 8.5.5 but its not a feasible option and cannot be done so easily across all the environments.

please provide the solution if you have any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then restart it periodically from crontab.

Comment: What files is it  opening at steady state?  Does "8.5" mean 8.5.0.0?  If so, just bite the bullet and do the routine upgrade.

Comment: The open files/connections are between dmgr and node agents. Yes we have 8.5.0

Comment: Are you saying thousands of sockets are opened and not closed? FWIW,  I would have started there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the nofiles softlimit to at least 10000, as recommended by IBM documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tprf_tuneaix.html?lang=en

1. Edit the /etc/security/limits file. Add the following lines to the user account that the WebSphere Application Server process runs on:

> ```
> nofiles =  10000
> nofiles_hard = 10000
> ```

2. Save the changes.
3. Restart your AIX system.
4. To verify the result, type the ulimit -a command on the command line.

That said, this might just delay your issue, and running on 8.5.0.0 is really not a good idea. Upgrading to the latest version (8.5.5.7) can be done in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details regarding the "Too many open file"  message that is logged?

In any case, +1 to upgrading. Version 8.5.0.0 is ~2 years old.